# How to show multiple timeseries plots using seaborn

Tags: pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I'm trying to generate 4 plots from a DataFrame using Seaborn

```
Date        A       B       C       D
2019-04-05  330.665 161.975 168.69  0
2019-04-06  322.782 150.243 172.539 0
2019-04-07  322.782 150.243 172.539 0
2019-04-08  295.918 127.801 168.117 0
2019-04-09  282.674 126.894 155.78  0
2019-04-10  293.818 133.413 160.405 0
```

I have casted dates using pd.to_DateTime and numbers using pd.to_numeric. Here is the df.info():

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6 entries, 460 to 465
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Date  6 non-null datetime64[ns]
A     6 non-null float64
B     6 non-null float64
C     6 non-null float64
D     6 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(4)
memory usage: 288.0 bytes
```

I can do a wide column plot by just calling .plot() on df.

However,

1. The legend of the plot is covering the plot itself
2. I would instead like to have 4 separate plots in 1 diagram and have tried  using lmplot to achieve this.
3. I would like to add labels to the plot like so:

   [Plot with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MEBK.png)

I first melted the data:

```
df=pd.melt(df,id_vars='Date', var_name='Var', value_name='Unit')
```

And then tried lmplot

```
sns.lmplot(x = df['Date'], y='Unit', col='Var', data=df)
```

However, I get the traceback:

```
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and str
```

I have also tried setting df.set_index['Date'] and replotting that using x=df.index and that gave me the same error.

The data can be plotted using Google Sheets but I am trying to automate a workflow where the chart can be generated and sent via Slack to selected recipients.

I hope I have expressed myself clearly enough as I am rather new to Python and Seaborn and hope to get some help from the experts here.

Comment: Have you considered using [plotly](https://plot.ly/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the legend you can just use `.legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))` as in this example

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = np.random.rand(10,4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
df.plot()\
  .legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1));
```

While for the second IIUC you can play from

```
df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(2,2));
```